# Excel contents into SQL Server table using Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005, excel

I'm creating an application where the user clicks on a button, browses for an Excel file, and the data is copied into the data table created in the database.

I am using VS2008 and SQL Server 2005.

I wrote code for opening the file of course, and created a dataTable and its dataColumns in the .cs file. What else should I do?

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at my answere [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942464/excel-to-datatable/4942571#4942571)

Answer (score 0):

You can write like the code below to dump the data into the SQL Server table

```
string excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("ImportFile.xls") + ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"""; 
    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString))
    {
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("Select * FROM [NameOfTheDataSheet$]", connection);
        connection.Open();

        using (DbDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            string sqlConnectionString = "SQL Connection String"; 
            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString))
            {
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "ExcelDataTable";
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataReader);
            }
        }
    }
```

Let me know if you have different requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You could do as Krishna advises... but that code will only work if the columns in the excel file and Database columns are the same in number and order.  For ease of maintainability and mapping down the line I highly recommend you use a combination of Linq to Excel and Linq to SQL as in this article:

http://solidcoding.blogspot.com/2008/01/linq-to-excel-sql-import.html