# Take contents of an excel file (.xls or .xlsx) in to Dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, exceldatareader

i have an excel file named test.xls and i want to get the contents in the excel sheet into a Dataset.Is it possible
i tried a code but it throws exception,here is my code

```
 string FilePath = Server.MapPath("portals\\_default") + "\\" + upprice.FileName;
 upprice.PostedFile.SaveAs(FilePath);
 FileStream stream = File.Open(FilePath, FileMode.Open,    FileAccess.Read);
 if (upprice.FileName.Contains(".xlsx"))
 {
  IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
   DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
 }
```

Comment: Can you post the exception details?

Comment: You can use an OLE adapter with a reference to your Excel spreadsheet in your connection string and query it like any other SQL datasouce.  See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942464/excel-to-datatable

Comment: @jacob..  i tried that solution ..its showing error

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you're using this http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/

From your code:

```
if (upprice.FileName.Contains(".xlsx"))
 {
  IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
   DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
 }
 else if (upprice.FileName.Contains(".xls"))
 {
  IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
  DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
 }
```

these tests are backwards. ".xlsx" files are zipped xml documents. "xls" are the older binary files. Also consider using System.IO.Path.GetExtension() to get the file extension since you'll notice Contains(".xls") is true for both file types.

Comment: I would say you need to use CreateBinaryReader for XLS and CreateOpenXmlReader for XLSX.